# Не меняется цвет текста в css

Tags: css

```css
.body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;

}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Container==================================================*/
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

/*Header==================================================*/
.header {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.header__inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


/*Nav==================================================*/

.nav {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #000;
}

.nav__link{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,500;0,600;0,700;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="header__inner">
         <nav class="nav">
                 <a href="nav__link" href="#">Главная</a>
                 <a href="nav__link" href="#">О библиотеке</a>
                 <a href="nav__link" href="#">Информационные ресурсы</a>
                 <a href="nav__link" href="#">Читателям</a>
                 <a href="nav__link" href="#">Библиотекарям</a>
              </nav>

              <div class="header__search-box">
                  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Ввелите текст...">
                  <a class="search-btn" href="#"></a>
              </div>
              
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

смотри внимательно на тег `a` - почему там 2 `href` ?
и посмотри порядок подключения шрифта со стилями

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/536793)

Comment: Справка -> Как публиковать ответы - `Любой ответ, который направляет спрашивающего в нужное русло, является ценным`

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть так:
`<a class="nav__link" href="#">Главная</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Не заданы стили вашим ссылкам. Всё должно иметь стили. И да правильно заметили, что у вас 2 "href": это - href="nav__link" замените на это - class="nav__link"

```css
.body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;

}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Container==================================================*/
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

/*Header==================================================*/
.header {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.header__inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


/*Nav==================================================*/

.nav {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #000;
}
.nav a {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.nav a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.nav__link{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,500;0,600;0,700;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="header__inner">
         <nav class="nav">
                 <a class="nav__link" href="#">Главная</a>
                 <a class="nav__link" href="#">О библиотеке</a>
                 <a class="nav__link" href="#">Информационные ресурсы</a>
                 <a class="nav__link" href="#">Читателям</a>
                 <a class="nav__link" href="#">Библиотекарям</a>
              </nav>

              <div class="header__search-box">
                  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Ввелите текст...">
                  <a class="search-btn" href="#"></a>
              </div>
              
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```